# Remove default legend symbol "a" from ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

The default symbol in the legend is a lowercase "a". When I try to use points on the plot using `geom_point(size=n)` it will simply overlay this symbol; but if the point is not big enough, the lowercase "a" is still visible. How can I remove this completely and just use the `geom_point`.

Legend with overlaid point

[image]

Legend without `geom_point`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `show.legend = FALSE` :

```
myggplot + geom_text(show.legend=FALSE)
```